# Trivial Equality in Lebesgue Decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1871.pdf) of a short proof of the Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem, the author claims the equality of additivity is "trivial". I do not see how this is so. Could someone help explain?

In particular the line about $\mu_{ac}$ being finitely additive.